# Make a post disappear if the date is older than today

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

Currently, I'm doing a website which repertories events organized my friend's music label. But I've encountered a problem while trying to make an "archiving automation". Using that code below is not working. My "articles" are still visibles on the *blog* page.

Here's what I've tried (it's working with a `v-if` on my `nuxt-link`, but not with a `v-show`). The reason why I don't use a `v-if` is that my links are still clickable, but not visible.

```html
<div
  class="article"
  v-for="article in articles"
  :key="article.slug"
  v-show="dateNow < article.eventDate">
```

Here's my condition in my JS (not important but I prefer to show you guys)

```
data() {
  return {
    dateNow: new Date().toISOString()
  };
},
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. But still: older means that it is < today (or today > older). Your code check in reverse. And, as @Mina says, check the dates & how to compare two dates in JS.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the formatting of the date.

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

this will format the date as a string.
So the output value for ( >= ) operation will be incorrect.
One solution is to turn the date into a timestamp by providing "+" before the date and then make the logical operation.
ex:

```
+new Date()
```

or

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Or if you use a date library like "moment" you can use isSameOrAfter or isSameOrBefore APIs.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/

Comment: I didn't know about MomentJS ! Thank you for sharing. `article.eventDate` is in ISO format by default probably caused by NetlifyCMS (used for my friend who's having none knowledge about dev).

Comment: You are welcome, Just to notify MomentJs is a rich library but it is a bit heavy for small projects if your project is small, I recommend using a lightweight library like luxon or date-fns.

Comment: Hi, please do not use Moment.js anymore since it's deprecated and not maintained anymore. Better alternatives exist as shown here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/